# How do I alter a language item link?

Tags: 8, navigation, theming

I am looking to modify the default output of Drupal 8 of links in a certain situation, the language switcher. Ideally I want to be able to do that in a twig template and not have to produce a [massive php file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198507/how-to-theme-a-link-in-twig-d8/198511#198511) that overwwrites that whole link generation system and add a BIG if for the cases I need to overwrite.

I think the output layout should be controllable in the twig template similar to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198507/how-to-theme-a-link-in-twig-d8/198511#answer-198563) (this answer outputs the same url for every languages)

I am using bootstrap as a base theme so i'd like to use the bootstrap markup for my links (btn btn-primary, dropdown)

Here is my code I am trying to make `links--language-block.html.twig`

```
{%- if links|length == 2 -%}
    {# show only alternate language button #}
    {%- for key, item in links -%}
        {%- if not item.attributes['#options']['set_active_class'] -%} {# <--- this is always true!? #}
            <a href="{{ item.link['#url'] }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ item.link['#title'] }}</a> {# #url is always the same what ever the language it is pointing to! #}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- elseif links|length > 2  -%}
    {# show selected language in button and other languages in drop down #}
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ selectedLanguage }}<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for key, item in links %}
            {%- if not item.attributes['#options']['set_active_class'] -%} {# <--- this is always true!? #}
            <li><a href="{{ item.link['#url'] }}">{{ item.link['#title'] }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{%- endif -%}
```

Anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok I found 2 ways to do that.

#### 1. In a custom theme

You can alter variables in your `my_theme.theme` file. You need to figure out the name of the function you need. ex: `my_theme_preprocess_twig_file()`, in my case I needed `my_theme_preprocess_links__language_block()` You need to take the twig file name and replace all `-` for `_`.

`my_theme.theme`:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_links__language_block(&$variables) {
  $currentLanguageCode = \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage()
    ->getId();
  // replace key of active language with 'activeLink'
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $i => $link) {
    /** @var \Drupal\language\Entity\ConfigurableLanguage $linkLanguage */
    $linkLanguage = $link['link']['#options']['language'];
    if ($currentLanguageCode == $linkLanguage->get('id')) {
      $variables['links']['activeLink'] = $link;
      unset($variables['links'][$i]);
    }
  }
  // if there is only 2 languages remove active one
  if (sizeof($variables['links']) == 2) {
    unset($variables['links']['activeLink']);
    // give class 'btn btn-primary' to alternate language
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Url $alternate */
    $alternate = current($variables['links']);
    $alternate['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn';
    $alternate['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-primary';
    $variables['links'] = [$alternate];
  }
}
```

#### 2. In a custom module

You can also create a module that will change those same variables. There is a big difference in the values of the variables because this preprocess happened earlier in the flow. The name of the function is also quite different, ex: `my_module_api_to_modify_alter()`. In my case I needed to modify the `language_switch_links` from the `language.api.php`. You can find all alter function by searching for `*.api.php` files in drupal 8. Those are there as a reference for exactly that.

`my_module.module`:

```
function my_module_language_switch_links_alter(&$variables) {
  $currentLanguageCode = \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage()
    ->getId();
  // replace key of active language with 'activeLink'
  foreach ($variables as $i => $link) {
    /** @var \Drupal\language\Entity\ConfigurableLanguage $linkLanguage */
    $linkLanguage = $link['language'];
    if ($currentLanguageCode == $linkLanguage->get('id')) {
      $variables['activeLink'] = $link;
      unset($variables[$i]);
    }
  }
  // if there is only 2 languages remove active one
  if (sizeof($variables) == 2) {
    unset($variables['activeLink']);
    // give class 'btn btn-primary' to alternate language
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Url $alternate */
    $alternate = current($variables);
    $alternate['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn';
    $alternate['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-primary';
    $variables = [$alternate];
  }
}
```

And my Twig template for both cases l`inks--language-block.html.twig`:

```
{% if links -%}
    {%- if links|length == 1 -%}
        {# show only alternate language button #}
        {{ (links|first).link }}
    {%- else -%}
        {# show selected language in button and other languages in drop down #}
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ links['activeLink'].text }} <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for key, item in links %}
                {% if key is not same as("activeLink") %}
                <li>{{ item.link }}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this adaption the language switcher so that when it finds a node with type article, and this is not a translation in a different langauge that it would change the link to be the homepage.

This needed to be made in a module rather than in the Theme.

I needed this as I had a massive difference in the number of translated articles per language.

```
function HOOK_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, \Drupal\Core\Url $url){
$currentLanguageCode = \Drupal::languageManager()
->getCurrentLanguage()
->getId();
// look at all links.
foreach ($links as $link) {
  // Only work on links that are not in the current page language.
  $lang_id = $link['language']->get('id');
  if ($currentLanguageCode != $lang_id) {
    // Trying to get the node.
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    // Making sure its an object and has the method getType and is Article.
    if (!empty((object) $node) 
      && method_exists($node, 'getType')
      && $node->getType() == 'article') {
      //  We know its an article, checking for languages.
      $flipped = array_flip(array_keys($node->getTranslationLanguages()));
      // Using flipped array rather than in_array
      if (!isset($flipped[$lang_id])) {
        // Translation not available.
        $links[$lang_id]['url'] = Url::fromRoute('<front>');
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Don't forget to add the use statement for Drupal\Core\Url and remove it from the function arguments, its also used for the new route generation.

Also note that you have to use a new generated Url object to change the url, there is no set method for the existing url ('<current>') to change it.