# How to display language switcher block as buttons, instead of simple links?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

the language switch block looks like this:

[image]

I would like to display it as bootstrap buttons or whatever else is possible. At least not in plain links.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Now in my D8 core, I found the PHP file for the language switcher, but I don't see where i can put my HTML code.

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Language switcher' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "language_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Language switcher"),
 *   category = @Translation("System"),
 *   deriver = "Drupal\language\Plugin\Derivative\LanguageBlock"
 * )
 */
class LanguageBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The language manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
   */
  protected $languageManager;

  /**
   * The path matcher.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Path\PathMatcherInterface
   */
  protected $pathMatcher;

  /**
   * Constructs an LanguageBlock object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager
   *   The language manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Path\PathMatcherInterface $path_matcher
   *   The path matcher.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager, PathMatcherInterface $path_matcher) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
    $this->pathMatcher = $path_matcher;
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('language_manager'),
      $container->get('path.matcher')
    );
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    $access = $this->languageManager->isMultilingual() ? AccessResult::allowed() : AccessResult::forbidden();
    return $access->addCacheTags(['config:configurable_language_list']);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = array();
    $route_name = $this->pathMatcher->isFrontPage() ? '<front>' : '<current>';
    $type = $this->getDerivativeId();
    $links = $this->languageManager->getLanguageSwitchLinks($type, Url::fromRoute($route_name));

    if (isset($links->links)) {
      $build = array(
        '#theme' => 'links__language_block',
        '#links' => $links->links,
        '#attributes' => array(
          'class' => array(
            "language-switcher-{$links->method_id}",
          ),
        ),
        '#set_active_class' => TRUE,
      );
    }
    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @todo Make cacheable in https://www.drupal.org/node/2232375.
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found now what helped me. Two modules do this:

1. [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) + [Language icon](https://www.drupal.org/project/languageicons) (the flags don't get displayed on D8 yet)

[image]

2. [Dropdown language Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropdown_language)

Answer (score 3):

***First choice***
If you wants some design related change you can easily achieve using **CSS**.

***Second choice***
Enable `twig.config: debug: true`

See some template file where you can made changes.

> FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
>   links--language-block.html.twig
>   links--language-block.html.twig
>   links.html.twig

[Changing markup of the language switcher](https://www.drupal.org/node/1369090)

***Trird choice***
Alter `_language_switch_links_alter`.
[How do I alter a language item link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199290/how-do-i-alter-a-language-item-link)

Comment: Thanks. Should I disable again twig config debug when I pass into live site?

Comment: yes you need to disable once move to live.

Comment: Okay. And for the CSS. The concept of modifying CSS in Drupal is really confusing to me. I found out the class of the language switcher with Inspector.`class="language-link is-active"`. Now I don't get it where I put my CSS code. There is no apparent CSS folder in the core. Excuse me for asking such trivial things.

Comment: You can put css in you default themes style.css or the css files included for you site.