# Global preprocess for all links

Tags: 8

Is there a some sort of global preprocessing hook for *any* link on a Drupal site?

Use case:

I've got an enquiry webform embedded on a node that presets some inputs by URL parameters. Editors can set links to that enquiry node on multiple different places on the site (in navigation menus, inside text fields using LinkIt, in URL fields,...).

Whenever the currently active context is a certain node type (e.g. on every full view of a product like "/product/product-id"), I want all links that are rendered on the page (e.g. menu links, blocks, entity reference field on the product pointing to the enquiry node, etc) to have the product_id appended.

I know how to get the current node id in preprocessing and I do know `hook_link_alter` for menus. But I wonder if there is some sort of global hook that captures *all* links, saving me from creating 453 different hooks doing all the same thing.

Comment: This might be of help https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198507/how-do-i-theme-a-link-from-a-template-file

Comment: @Hidri, How do you reference the webform from the node, using a webform reference field?

Comment: @Ziftman Yes, not directly though, the node has an intermediate paragraph field, and the paragraph contains the webform reference field.

Comment: So, whenever the currently active context is a product (e.g. /product/product-id), you want all links that are rendered on the page (e.g. menu links, blocks, entity reference field on the product pointing to the enquiry node, etc) to have the product_id appended. Is that correct?

Comment: @Stefanos Petrakis: Yes, exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be by using a service tagged with the `path_processor_outbound` service tag.
Your service should then implement the `processOutbound()` function in order to modify all links on a page, if the request delivers a node object of the type you want.

This is an example service definition using the described service tag:

```
services:
  dummy.link_modifier_service:
    class: Drupal\dummy\DefaultService
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_outbound }
    arguments: ['@request_stack']
```

This is an example implementation of such a service:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\dummy;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;

/**
 * Class DefaultService.
 */
class DefaultService implements DefaultServiceInterface, OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack definition.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;
  /**
   * Constructs a new DefaultService object.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {

    if (empty($request)) {
      $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }
    $node = $request->attributes->get('node');
    if ($node && $node->bundle() === 'product') {
      $options['query'][] = [$node->bundle() . '_id' => $node->id()];
    }
    return $path;
  }  

}
```

This code will now be modifying all Drupal-handled URLs and adding a product_id=XX parameter to them.

Hope this helps, good luck!

@see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21OutboundPathProcessorInterface.php/function/OutboundPathProcessorInterface%3A%3AprocessOutbound/

Comment: Thanks, this worked for both, link fields and links inside text fields / CKeditor. @Stefanos, it might be helpful for others to include a `services.yml` example in your answer, I didn't know first how to use the `tags`. You can copy it from my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/hudri/0913a2086ed0c0d70c9828724c8728c2)

Comment: This works great. I notice the `<link>` tags in the head also inherits the changes (i.e. canonical, alternate, shortlink, etc).

Comment: @Hudri happy it worked, thanks for the gist, I updated the answer accordingly, including a mod version of it.

Comment: Addendum: This solution also needs a cache context for links in blocks or menus, otherwise you might get cached links without added parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to alter all links then you need to adjust the input for the preRenderLink and add the query to the element before its generated.

Firs you implement this hook_element_info_alter to use your own class which extends the core Link class

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function custom_element_info_alter(array &$info) {
  $info['link']['#pre_render'] = [
    [Drupal\custom\Links\CustomLink::class, 'preRenderLink'],
  ];
}
```

You extends the Link class and add your check if true then you can inject the parameters to your query

```
namespace Drupal\custom\Links;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Link;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

class CustomLink extends Link {

  public static function preRenderLink($element) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof NodeInterface && $node->getType() == 'product') {
      $element['#options']['query']['product_id'] = $node->id();
    }

     return parent::preRenderLink($element);
  }

}
```

Another solution can be with javascript which not recommended. You can take look how [extlink module](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink) is changing the links icon based on the link if it's external or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is related to my problem. If I understand it correctly, this modifies how the webform field is rendered on the node. But my problem is with links to the node *anywhere* on the site, e.g. a link to the enquiry node in a menu or a block.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I've edited it according to @Stefanos Petrakis' comment on the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Hudri that what you want?

Comment: Thanks, this is the starting point I needed, first tests look very promising

Comment: Hm, seems to work very well with link fields, but not with links inside CKeditor / a textfield.

Comment: @Hudri for sure it will work with everything but not with the text which is stored inside fields, the links in the text it's not rendered by Drupal, there is another method to deal with that, you can solve it many ways, you would use the preprocess for the FIELD  to add the suffix you want and this would use preg_match with regular expression to find all the links or you can use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view

Comment: I finally used Stefanos' version, it better fits my use case. Your solution has the advantage of working with internal and external links, while Stefanos version only works with interal links. But Stefanos' version also works with links in text field, so I ended up using his solution. But thanks for your effort, it helped me understanding D8 better.

Comment: This what is nice about Drupal, you can do what you want in many ways :)