# How do I set a url query parameter node/{node}/edit for a specific content type?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms, routes, path-aliases

I'm trying to add a taxonomy term from the node in question as a url parameter, but am struggling to figure out how to do it without just going through the site and modifying all of the links that point to it.

So currently the path looks like this

```
node/{node}/edit?destination=/plan
```

I'd like to modify if to look like this for a specific content type.

```
node/{node}/edit?destination=/plan&year={field_plan_year}
```

Should this be done in the routes file? Can it be done in hook_form_alter? Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I might look for an example of this? Can this be done with something like Pathauto?

The reason behind my need for this is to filter a view (that is shown via the form template). The node edit screen shares a matching programmatically generated taxonomy term (in this case "year"). We need to be able to contextually filter the view based on the value of the term from within the node.

Comment: I wouldn't look to deeply in this query thingy. The root of your problem is: How to redirect after node form submit to a URL retrieved from a node value. Isn't it that? So maybe search for: node form redirect. And you'll probably find what you need.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to append the query so that on the edit screen I can show a contextually filtered view (one that happens to share a taxonomy term with the node in question). Does that make sense? I don't think a node form redirect would handle it, unless that redirect was to the same form, but added the query. In this use case we generate several of the values in the node form programmatically one of which is a taxonomy term for year that is always set.

Comment: This is some key information. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Updated. I hope that makes sense. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: This requirement looks similar to a question I had myself a few month ago. You maybe could use an OutboundPathProcessor, see the answer from Stefanos Petrakis in this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259326/global-preprocess-for-all-links)

Comment: Hey Hudri, Thanks for the info. I grabbed the code out of your gist. Added a perf_plan.services.yml and src/LinkModifierService.php changed all of the namespacing/classnames (per my module name) and updated the node bundle to perf_plan (my bundle name). After removing DefaultServiceInterface (from the original example) which was causing an error, I'm not seeing any changes to the url at either node/1 or node/1/edit (both which correspond to my perf_plan bundle). What behavior do you see when you visit a node with the bundle of product on your setup?

Comment: It adds a GET parameter to every outgoing link from this page. Notice that those link might be cached if they are in a block or similar, I also had to add a cache context (without cache context the parameter adding only worked inside the node content, but not in menus)