# Subdomain for each node from content type

Tags: 8, nodes

Is there any way to automatically create subdomain for each node from some content type?

I have a lot of pages that should be created and each should be on separated subdomain, I'm trying to find the way to do that through current website on Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an outbound path processor and modify `$options['base_url']`, see [LanguageNegotiationUrl::processOutbound](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21Plugin%21LanguageNegotiation%21LanguageNegotiationUrl.php/function/LanguageNegotiationUrl%3A%3AprocessOutbound/8.6.x). This method is from a language negotiation plugin, but you can place directly in a service tagged `path_processor_outbound`, see [Global preprocess for all links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260113/47547)