# How can I override the base URL as sent in one-time login links when decoupled front-end domains differ from the backend domain?

Tags: 9

For a decoupled project I'm using a passwordless authentication flow, which means I'm using the `/user/password?_format=json` endpoint to send one-time-login links to users. In the frontend I've created a page to proxy the one-time-login link.

Since I'm using multiple domains for the frontend I want to override the base url of the absolute URL's with a value given as query parameter.

How can I override the base URL as sent in a query parameter?

For Example:

When sending a request to

```
https://api.example.com/user/password?_format=json&base_url=example.com
```

The default behavior of Drupal is to send a one-time-login link like this:

```
https://api.example.com/user/reset/<UID>/<TIMESTAMP>/<HASH>
```

But I want the one-time-login link to be this:

```
https://example.com/user/reset/<UID>/<TIMESTAMP>/<HASH>
```

Comment: Maybe you can put the logic in a custom token?

Comment: The Drupal Url object has the option `base_url`. If you don't have a chance to add the option in the code creating the URL you can use an outbound path processor to alter the URL.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! A question like *Is there any hook, event subscriber, module or anything to accomplish this?* is too broad to be acceptable. At least, the question should be limited to only hooks, event subscribers, or modules, but then a question asking to find or recommend modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources are off-topic for us.

Comment: To avoid to be closed for that reason, the question should not only describe what you are trying to achieve, but also what you tried so far, and in which way what you obtained is different from what you expected to obtain. If you are asking the question before trying to achieve what described or reading documentation, you are asking the question too early.

Comment: Furthermore, a question about a hook to use would be acceptable if it asked the difference between two hooks, what exactly the documentation for a hook means, or which hook should be used in Drupal N+1 which is equivalent to the hook used in Drupal N. Given the questions already asking that for different Drupal 7 hooks, it's probable that, in the latter case, the question has been already asked and answered.

Comment: @4uk4 The Outbound Path Processor did the trick!

```
 public function processOutbound($path, &$options = [], Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    if (!empty($request->query->get('base_url'))) {
      $options['base_url'] = $request->query->get('base_url');
    }

    return $path;
  }
```

Comment: I edited the question and voted to reopen it. Then you can post your code as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the comments into an answer:

The Drupal Url object has the option `base_url`:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('user.login', [], ['base_url' => 'http://www.example.com']);
```

If you don't have a chance to add the option in the code creating the URL you can use an outbound path processor to alter the URL:

```
public function processOutbound($path, &$options = [], Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
  if (!empty($request->query->get('base_url'))) {
    $options['base_url'] = $request->query->get('base_url');
  } 
  return $path; 
}
```

This is a minimal code example, make it more safe by checking the query parameter for valid domains and the path where it should apply.

More info about path processing [Global preprocess for all links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259326/global-preprocess-for-all-links)